# IText: cannot set СryptoDictionary property of PdfSignatureAppearance

Tags: c#, itext

There was a code using iTextSharp:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(document);
PdfStamper st = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, new FileStream(document + "_signed.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write), '\0');                        
PdfSignatureAppearance sap = st.SignatureAppearance;

// something

PdfSignature dic = new PdfSignature(filterName, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
sap.CryptoDictionary = dic;
```

I need to write it using iText7:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"C:\Users\RakuVIu\Documents\rozha.pdf");
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(document + "_signed.pdf", FileMode.Create), new StampingProperties());
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.GetSignatureAppearance();

// something

PdfSignature signature = new PdfSignature(filterName, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached);
appearance.SetCryptoDictionary(signature); // no such method!
```

So, I cannot set CryptoDictionary property, because there is no method or property to do it.

Comment: The iText 7 signing API attempts to hide implementation details which shouldn't be used anymore since the 5.3.x signature API overhaul, and the signature dictionary is such a detail. Is there any reason why you have to use the pre-5.3.x API?

Comment: @mkl I have an example written using itextsharp, and I'm not familiar with it's object model ((

Comment: Then you could explain the use case and post your current code, so people here can get an idea.

Comment: @mkl I think that I can't post code example cause it may be a commercial property, but I can definitely tell the purpose. I need to sign PDF file with x509certificate.

Comment: That's definitively too little information to go by. If you are not allowed to provide more information, you should study the [iText Digital Signatures white paper](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf/intro). You can find iTextSharp/.Net examples corresponding to the Java examples in the white paper [here](https://github.com/itext/i5ns-tutorial/tree/master/signatures). Based on that you can see what your signing code should have been ported to at the time of iTextSharp 5.3.x. The iText 7 / .Net signing API is derived from the signing API presented in the white paper.

Comment: @mkl Ok, I'll check it

Comment: @mkl Thank you. If you'll post your first comment as an answer, I'll pick it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iText 7 signing API attempts to hide implementation details which shouldn't be used anymore since the 5.3.x signature API overhaul, and the signature dictionary is such a detail.

For details on the signature API introduced in the 5.3.x versions, please read the [iText Digital Signatures white paper](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/books/digital-signatures-pdf/intro). The Java examples in there have been ported to C# and can be accessed [here](https://github.com/itext/i5ns-tutorial/tree/master/signatures).

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to this party but we had the same problem when migrating from iTextSharp to iText 7. We use a dictionary to store extra metadata about a signature. Luckily there is still support in iText by means of an `ISignatureEvent` interface. You will have to implement this interface and register it with the PdfSigner object (through a `SetSignatureEvent(...)` call).

So in short your interface implementation should look like this:

```
public class ClassThatImplementsISignatureEvent: ISignatureEvent
{
  public void GetSignatureDictionary(PdfSignature sig)
  {
    var dict = (PdfDictionary)sig.GetPdfObject();
    dict.Put(new PdfName("SomeData"), new PdfString("SomeValue"));
  }
}
```

And of course you will have to register it before you call `SignDetached()` or `SignExternalContainer()`:

```
PdfSigner signer = new iText.Signatures.PdfSigner(...);
...
signer.SetSignatureEvent(new ClassThatImplementsISignatureEvent());
...
signer.SignDetached(...)
```